# Given a matrix print the given triangle

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

**Given 2 dimensional:**

```
int[,] arr2d = new int[3,3]
                            {
                                {1, 2, 3}, 
                                {4, 5, 6}, 
                                {7, 8, 9} 
                            };
```

**Objective:** Print the 2d array in the given triangle pattern so it appears as below:
[image]

Comment: ...and what are the rules on how we get from the 2D array to that picture?  Give us more explanation.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I thought this is print along its main diagonal.

[image: picture].

In the example case, we list the indices of `arr2d`:

```
(0, 2)
(0, 1), (1, 2)
(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)
(1, 0), (2, 1)
(2, 0)
```

See the regular pattern?

- In the first 3 lines, the `x` of first element on each line remains `0`, and the `y` decreases.
- In the last 3 lines, the `y` of first element on each line remains `0`, and the `x` increases.
- In each line, next element relative to previous is `(x++, y++)`, until either `x` or `y` ≥3.

---

For more general way, a `n` dimensional matrix has `2n-1` line of trangle.

- In the first `n` lines, the `x` of first element remains to `0`, the `y` decreases.
- In the last `n` lines, the `y` of first element remains to `0`, the `x` increases.
- For each line, print `(x++, y++)` until either `x` or `y` ≥3.

---

Here's the code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int[,] arr2d = new int[3,3]
                    {
                        {1, 2, 3}, 
                        {4, 5, 6}, 
                        {7, 8, 9} 
                    };

    int dimension = 3;
    int x = 0, y = dimension - 1

    while(y >= 0) {
        WriteDiagalNumbers(arr2d, x, y, dimension);
        y--;
        // or shorten as
        // WriteDiagalNumbers(arr2d, x, y--, dimension);
    }

    x = 1;
    y = 0;

    while(x < dimension) {
        WriteDiagalNumbers(arr2d, x, y, dimension);
        x++;
        // or shorten as
        // WriteDiagalNumbers(arr2d, x++, y, dimension);
    }

}

static void WriteDiagalNumbers(int[,] arr, int x, int y, int dimension) {
    List<int> nums = new List<int>();

    while(x < dimension && y < dimension) {
        nums.Add(arr[x, y]);
        x++;
        y++;
        // or shorten as
        // nums.Add(arr[x++, y++]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", nums));
}
```

Gives the output:

```
3
2, 6
1, 5, 9
4, 8
7
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Sheey's answer, though it bothers me that the array dimensions are hard-coded in that solution.  So here's a generic approach using [GetUpperBound()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=netcore-3.1) to determine the number of rows/columns.

Calling `GetUpperBound(0)` would tell you how many ROWS, while `GetUpperBound(1)` would give the number of COLUMNS.

We can get the coordinates of all the diagonal starting positions by starting in the upper right corner of the array and moving left.  Once we hit the left side we travel down the array.  From each of those starting positions we get the diagonal values by incrementing both of the starting x/y positions while they are within the bounds of the array.  This is one of those rare occasions where a `for` loop with multiple variables can be used.

The code also pads the output based on the largest value so that the triangle can handle any size integers.

Note that when accessing a 2D array, the `x` and `y` parameters are reversed:

```
arr[y, x]
```

You list the `y` value as the first parameter, and the `x` value as the second parameter.

So with this array:

```
int[,] arr2d = new int[,]
                {
                    {85, 86, 87, 88},
                    {89, 90, 91, 92},
                    {93, 94, 95, 96},
                    {97, 98, 99, 100}
                }
```

The 88 value, using zero based notation, would be normally thought of as at coordinates (2, 0), but would be accessed with `arr2d[0, 2]`.

Similarly, the 97 value would be normally thought of as at coordinates (0, 2), but would be accessed with `arr2d[2, 0]`.

I felt this approach was different enough to warrant an additional answer to the question:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] arr2d = new int[,]
                    {
                        {85, 86, 87, 88},
                        {89, 90, 91, 92},
                        {93, 94, 95, 96},
                        {97, 98, 99, 100}
                    };

    printTriangle(arr2d);

    Console.Write("Press Enter to quit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void printTriangle(int[,] arr)
{
    // Get all the starting positions for "diagonals":
    // Start in the top right of the array,
    // then move all the way left,
    // followed by all the way down.
    int y = 0;
    int x = arr.GetUpperBound(1);
    bool travelLeft = true;
    bool triangleComplete = false;
    List<string> diagonalValues = new List<string>();
    int pad = arr.Cast<int>().Max().ToString().Length;

    while (!triangleComplete)
    {
        diagonalValues.Clear();    
        for(int yTemp = y, xTemp = x;
            xTemp <= arr.GetUpperBound(1) && yTemp <= arr.GetUpperBound(0);
            xTemp++, yTemp++)
        {
            diagonalValues.Add(arr[yTemp, xTemp].ToString().PadLeft(pad));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", diagonalValues));

        if (travelLeft)
        {
            x--; // move left
            travelLeft = (x > 0);
        }                
        else
        {
            y++; // move down
            triangleComplete = (y > arr.GetUpperBound(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 88
 87,  92
 86,  91,  96
 85,  90,  95, 100
 89,  94,  99
 93,  98
 97
Press Enter to quit...
```